# A population error of mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have defined a `PostSchema` by mongoose:

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
  editor: { post: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }, codes: [{ type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Code' }] }
});
```

I can use `http://localhost:3000/#/posts/5879fc91b7a56002237f30f5` to show all the comments because of this code:

```
router.get('/posts/:post', function (req, res, next) {
    req.post.populate('comments', function (err, post) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }

        res.json(post);
    });
});
```

Now, I want to use `http://localhost:3000/#/posts/5879fc91b7a56002237f30f5/editor` to get all the content of `editor`, including `codes` inside. But the following code prints `["5892bbc68abcc926f7f1dd93","5892bbdf8abcc926f7f1dd94","5892bc178abcc926f7f1dd95","5892bc1b8abcc926f7f1dd96"]`:

```
router.get('/posts/:post/editor', function (req, res, next) {
    req.post.editor.populate('codes', function (err, editor) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(editor.codes));
        res.json(editor);
    })
});
```

Does anyone know how to populate `codes` correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this you have give reference to a model.

```
 router.get('/posts/:post/editor', function (req, res, next) {
        req.post.populate({path:'editor.codes',model:'Code'}, function (err, editor) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(editor.codes));
            res.json(editor);
        })
    });
```

Comment: I tried `req.post.editor.populate({path:'codes',model:'Code'}, function (err, editor)...`, it still just printed ids...

Comment: edited the answer try it now. I don't get why were you writing post.editor ?

Comment: I can not test it now. Just a quick remark: if we use `req.post.populate(`, should we use `function (err, editor)` or `function (err, post)`?

Comment: it wont effect both are one and the same thing editor or post both are the parameters which will contain your result that comes from that query. Just try the above code it should work.